# If one can produce and consume from one topic, does that indicate that every other topic in kafka is in a healthy state?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, apache-kafka

If one can push and consume from one topic in a kafka cluster of 3 brokers running in kubernetes with `auto_scaling disabled;` can that be used to draw a conclusion that we can successfully push and consume from all the other topics in a cluster?

```
Total brokers in the cluster: 3
Min-InSyncReplicas: 2
No. of partitions for eahc topic: 25
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. 
If you can produce and consume from a particular topic this is a good indication that everything is working in terms of 'communication' (successful consumption from `topic_a` does not mean that consumption from `topic_b` will also be OK). However, 'healthy state' is a quite subjective term. Kafka exposes several metrics via [JMX](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html) for Brokers, Consumers and Producers. Depending on your monitoring requirement you can choose the appropriate metric and decide/judge whether everything is OK (according to your requirements).

Note: If you are using Enterprise Confluent Platform these metrics can also be observed through [Confluent Control Center](https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/docs/index.html#control-center).

Comment: Might want to put some examples. Such as Min ISR and replication factors

Comment: Added more info. Thanks.

Comment: "successful consumption from topic_a does not mean that consumption from topic_b will also be OK" 
Could you please add why you think this is true? I believe it's true as well; but can't come up with a solid reason to explain this.